# Existing user_meta fields not updated

Tags: user-meta

Why am I not allowed to update existing user-meta fields when hooking on to `edit_user_profile_update` hook? I use this code

```
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'xpl_registration_save' );

function xpl_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $user->add_role( 'gardner' );
    update_user_meta($user_id,'last_name','Smith');
    update_user_meta($user_id,'dogs_name','Sam');
}
```

This works for the last field, `dogs_name`, which is added, and updated. But for core fields, some other fields which have been created by another plugin, it doesn't work. How come?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change some user meta fields using `edit_user_profile_update` hook,
because it is triggered **before** processing data from the form. So, you save user's meta to database, then edit form is processed and WP overrides your values. This hook is triggered after each profile edit.

You should use `insert_user_meta` filter (available since WP v4.4) to change or add user's meta. 
Filter is applied after user is created/updated, but meta has not yet been saved to the DB.

```
add_action( 'insert_user_meta', 'se329613_insert_user_meta', 30, 3);

/** 
 * @param array $meta {
 *     Default meta values and keys for the user.
 *
 *     @type string   $nickname
 *     @type string   $first_name
 *     @type string   $last_name
 *     @type string   $description
 *     @type bool     $rich_editing
 *     @type bool     $syntax_highlighting
 *     @type bool     $comment_shortcuts
 *     @type string   $admin_color
 *     @type int|bool $use_ssl
 *     @type bool     $show_admin_bar_front
 * }
 * @param WP_User $user
 * @param bool    $update 
 */
function se329613_insert_user_meta( $meta, $user, $update ) 
{
    // set only when adding a new user
    if ( !$update ) {
        $meta['last_name'] = 'Smith';
        $meta['dogs_name'] = 'Sam';
    }
    return $meta;
}
```

You can use the `user_register` action to perform other operations. Functions hooked to `user_register` 
are executed when everything is already saved.

```
add_action( 'user_register' , 'se329613_user_register' );
function se329613_user_register( $user_id ) 
{
    /* some code */
}
```